# matplotlib aspect ratio for narrow matrices

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a `200x3` matrix in python which I would like to plot. However, by using `Matplotlib` I get the following figure. How can I plot an image which looks nicer?

my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(spectrum_matrix)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`set_aspect()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

spectrum_matrix = np.random.rand(200,3)

plt.imshow(spectrum_matrix)
plt.axes().set_aspect('auto')
plt.show()
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: I would also set the `interpolation='none'` argument of `imshow` to make it clear that you show discrete values.